# How do I determine if a build is a scheduled job in CircleCI?

Tags: cron, scheduled-tasks, circleci

I would like to decide if a build is a scheduled job *from inside the build*.

For example, on Travis CI my build scripts look for the `$TRAVIS_EVENT_TYPE` environment variable to see if its value is `cron`.

How should I do this on CircleCI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a custom environment variable (envar). While you can't set an envar directly in a workflow, you can add one to a CircleCI Context, and then attach that context to the workflow. The envar name can be whatever you want and the value whatever you want.

One example would be to create a context called `nightly` when an envar in it that you can then check for in a job. Here's an example:

```
  nightly-build:                                                                                                                                                          
    triggers:                                                                                                                                                             
      - schedule:                                                                                                                                                         
          cron: "0 0 * * *"                                                                                                                                               
          filters:                                                                                                                                                        
            branches:                                                                                                                                                     
              only: master
    jobs:
      - build:
          context: nightly
```

Comment: Does this suggest that I can even distinguish between different cron jobs? Sounds fantatstic!

Comment: The green tick is pending, I'll give this a try.

Comment: Yes it does. Context is an extra layer of abstraction but allows you to flexibly have envars in jobs that vary depending on the specific workflow.

Comment: I just added a workflow with your config and it doesn't build (on push) anymore. I need it to build on every push *in addition* to scheduled jobs

Comment: Your config has two workflows now right? The original one you had, as well as a scheduled workflow.

Comment: I did not have a single workflow before this. There was only one job so it runs at every push.

Comment: With CircleCI 2.1, there's always a workflow, even when not explicitly defined. I'd suggest sharing your config (if you can) on CircleCI Discuss and we can get you some better help that way.

Comment: Looks like this new workflow has overridden the implicit, default one that triggers on push. I added another WF and problem solved.

Comment: Awesome thanks for letting me know. I'll see if we can get this edge case written down somewhere in our docs.